# Apache Commons hashCode builder inconsistent hashes

Tags: java, hashcode, apache-commons-lang3

I am using the hash code builder as an instance variable of a pojo.

```
public class Pojo {
private HashCodeBuilder hashBuilder = new HashCodeBuilder(); 
private int i;
public setI(int i) {this.i = i}

@Override
public int hashCode() {           
    hashBuilder.append(id);        
    return hashBuilder.toHashCode();
}
}
```

Now if I set the value of `i` to the same value twice, then my hashcode result will be different. Is this a bug in the implementation?

I understand that it is happening because the hash code builder keeps a running total. But should it not give the same hash for the same set of values?

Also, if I don't follow the above approach then I will end up initialising the same hash code builder within the `hashcode` method of my pojo  thousands of times as follows:

```
...
@Override
public int hashCode() {   
    hashBuilder = new HashBuilder();        
    hashBuilder.append(id);        
    return hashBuilder.toHashCode();
}
...
```

Is there a way to reset this running total so that every time I call `hashcode` with the same set of values I get a consistent answer?

Comment: And why would resetting be more efficient then creating a new instance? You shouldn't be reusing it in the first place imho. It would even fail with the same id and calling `hashCode` twice in a row.

Comment: well, you create one pojo and then end up calling hashcode `X` number of times. You will end up with `X` hash code builder objects which are potentially going to be garbage collected but you never know when that will happen. So until that time your memory usage increase. So I think it is better to have just one pojo?

Comment: NO it isn't. Especially not with short lived objects, they come more or less for free. They are gc'ed quite quick . Looks like premature optimization instead of a real measured thing.

Comment: hmm right then I'll assume no side effects of calling it X number of times - thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

The way you're doing it you're appending another `id` each time you call `hashCode()`. Since `append()` is accepting a value (not field name!), the `HashCodeBuilder` has no way to know whether you appended `id` twice or whether you have another field that has the same value in it.

Create the `HashCodeBuilder` locally in the `hashCode()`. Don't assume it would affect performance in a significant way unless you have profiled the application and proved that it does (aka. avoid premature optimization).

If you indeed want to avoid needless creation of `HashCodeBuilder` on each `hashCode()`, you'll have to track changes in setters and set the `hashCodeBuilder` to `null` whenever a value changes through setter; then use it in `hashCode()` if needed. Then you'd have to make sure all field modification go through setters. Quite a lot of work and many things can go wrong, so you really want to avoid all this if possible.

Comment: or simple solution would be to provide a reset method in the hash builder?

Comment: Obviously the library authors didn't see any need for such method. Creating a throwaway instance is cheap in Java. Instance variables affect thread-safety. Common usage is to only keep the instance locally in `hashCode()`, and if you want to go for the hash code caching, you'd do better caching the resulting hash code than keeping the builder anyway.

Comment: Update - I've just read through the builder implementation, threadlocal is used so thread safety would not be an issue.